# Insert a Cursor directly into a table in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have an instance of `sqlite.SQLiteCursor` and a `Table` which have the same schema (same columns). I want to insert data from cursor into the table. I can extract data from cursor and use `SQLiteDatabase#insert()` method, but is there a method that does them internally? For example if I have multiple tables and related cursors, creating multiple methods, for inserting, for each pair is time consuming task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a method that does them internally?

I don't believe so as a Cursor isn't necessarily the entire contents of a single table and often a Cursor can have derived columns (e.g. `column_x + column y AS new_column`) and columns from other joined tables.

It would be a relatively simple task to write a common method that if passed the table name and the Cursor to extract the column names (`Cursor#getColumnNames()`) and build the INSERT SQL for any cursor/table combination **IF** the Cursor and Table Column names matched (more difficult but possible to ignore column's not in the table perhaps utilising [the table_info PRAGMA](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info)).

Saying that an intermediate Cursor isn't necessarily required as you could use `INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM old_table;`

### Working Example (crude)

**DBhelper.java**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBL_MASTER = "master";
    public static final String COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COL_OTHER = "other";
    public static final String COL_MYBLOB = "myblob";
    public static final String COL_MYFLOAT = "myfloat";


    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String crt_table_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_MASTER + "(" +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COL_NAME + " TEXT," +
                COL_OTHER + " TEXT," +
                COL_MYBLOB + " BLOB," +
                COL_MYFLOAT + " REAL " +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_table_sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long insertData(String name, String other, byte[] myblob,float myfloat ) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COL_OTHER,other);
        cv.put(COL_MYBLOB,myblob);
        cv.put(COL_MYFLOAT,myfloat);
        return mDB.insert(TBL_MASTER,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAll() {
       return getFromTable(TBL_MASTER);
    }

    public Cursor getFromTable(String table_name) {
        return mDB.query(table_name,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public boolean createTableBasedUponAnotherTable(String existing_table_name, String new_table_name) {
        boolean rv = false;
        String sql_column = "sql";
        String whereclause = "name=? AND type = ?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{existing_table_name,"table"};
        String[] columns = new String[]{sql_column};
        Cursor csr = mDB.query("sqlite_master",columns,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            String sql = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(sql_column)).replace(existing_table_name,new_table_name).replace("CREATE TABLE","CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS");
            mDB.execSQL(sql);
            rv = true;
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    private boolean ifTableExists(String table_name) {
        boolean rv = false;
        String whereclause = "name=? AND type = ?";
        String[] whereargs = new String[]{table_name,"table"};
        Cursor csr = mDB.query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = true;
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public boolean copyTableViaCursor(Cursor csr, String table_name) {
        boolean rv = false;
        mDB.beginTransaction();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        int rows_processed;
        if(!ifTableExists(table_name)) {
            csr.moveToPosition(-1); // just in case position the cursor to before the first row
            while (csr.moveToNext()) {
                cv.clear();
                for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    switch  (csr.getType(i)) {
                        case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
                            cv.put(csr.getColumnName(i),csr.getBlob(i));
                            break;
                        case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                            cv.put(csr.getColumnName(i),csr.getFloat(i));
                            break;
                        case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                            cv.put(csr.getColumnName(i),csr.getInt(i));
                            break;
                        case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                            cv.put(csr.getColumnName(i),csr.getString(i));
                            break;
                    }
                }
                mDB.insert(table_name,null,cv);
            }
            mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }
        mDB.endTransaction();
        return rv;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    Cursor csr;
    String new_table = DBHelper.TBL_MASTER + "_new";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        mDBHlpr.insertData("Fred","more about fred",new byte[]{7,8,4,55,67,127,126,99},321.76894F);
        mDBHlpr.insertData("Bert","something or other about bert",new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},1234567890.675342F);
        mDBHlpr.insertData("Mary","definitely not something about Mary",new  byte[]{},0.000000000000F);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr = mDBHlpr.getAll());
        mDBHlpr.createTableBasedUponAnotherTable(DBHelper.TBL_MASTER,new_table);
        mDBHlpr.copyTableViaCursor(csr,new_table);
        csr = mDBHlpr.getFromTable(new_table);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

### Output in Log :-

```
2019-01-05 19:03:56.791 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@268ba35
2019-01-05 19:03:56.791 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: 0 {
2019-01-05 19:03:56.791 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    _id=1
2019-01-05 19:03:56.791 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    name=Fred
2019-01-05 19:03:56.791 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    other=more about fred
2019-01-05 19:03:56.792 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    myblob=<unprintable>
2019-01-05 19:03:56.792 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    myfloat=321.769
2019-01-05 19:03:56.792 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: }
2019-01-05 19:03:56.792 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: 1 {
2019-01-05 19:03:56.792 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    _id=2
2019-01-05 19:03:56.792 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    name=Bert
2019-01-05 19:03:56.792 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    other=something or other about bert
2019-01-05 19:03:56.792 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    myblob=<unprintable>
2019-01-05 19:03:56.792 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    myfloat=1.23457e+09
2019-01-05 19:03:56.793 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: }
2019-01-05 19:03:56.793 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: 2 {
2019-01-05 19:03:56.793 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    _id=3
2019-01-05 19:03:56.793 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    name=Mary
2019-01-05 19:03:56.793 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    other=definitely not something about Mary
2019-01-05 19:03:56.793 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    myblob=<unprintable>
2019-01-05 19:03:56.793 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    myfloat=0
2019-01-05 19:03:56.793 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: }
2019-01-05 19:03:56.793 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-01-05 19:03:56.795 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@268ba35
2019-01-05 19:03:56.795 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: 0 {
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    _id=1
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    name=Fred
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    other=more about fred
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    myblob=<unprintable>
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    myfloat=321.769
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: }
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: 1 {
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    _id=2
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    name=Bert
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    other=something or other about bert
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    myblob=<unprintable>
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    myfloat=1.23457e+09
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: }
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: 2 {
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    _id=3
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    name=Mary
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    other=definitely not something about Mary
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    myblob=<unprintable>
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out:    myfloat=0
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: }
2019-01-05 19:03:56.796 4211-4211/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor I/System.out: <<<<<
```

Comment: i dont know such method either but there is on old (Added in API level 1) and relatively less used class `ContentQueryMap` which gives a map of `ContentValues` based on the input `Cursor`